# How do you pass in data to custom directives as a value of the attribute itself?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive defined as such:

```
angular.module("main.directives").directive("todo", function() {

   return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
         todo: "=entity"
      },
      replace: false,
      templateUrl: "todo.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {       
      }
   };
});
```

which I use like this from templates:

```
<div todo entity="todoData"></div>
```

`todoData` comes from a controller or some other the local scope. Anyway it all works like a charm, so that's cool!

My question is the following: How do I have to modify the directive definition so that it also works with a markup of this type:

```
<div todo="todoData"></div>
```

As you can see the data is now passed in as the value of the attribute marking the directive. Just like `ng-` directives do:

```
<p ng-repeat="bit in data"></p>
<p ng-click="whatever()"></p>
```

How can that be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
scope: {
    todo: "=entity"
},
```

by

```
scope: {
    todo: "=todo"
},
```

or simply

```
scope: {
    todo: "="
},
```

Comment: Yeap, that's the way to do it. Here is a plnkr demonstrating the above http://plnkr.co/edit/o5OGMHWTZp6FT5itJmGy

Answer (score 1):

When you write an attribute directive in angularjs you might want to have it fed by an attribute value.
For example, something like this:

```
<div my-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

How then do you create a new scope that takes that in? It's not obvious. Any here's how you do it:

```
app.directive('myAttribute', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myAttribute: '='
        },
        template: '<div style="font-weight:bold">{{ myAttribute | number:2}}</div>'
    };
});
```

The trick to notice is that the "self attribute" because of the name of the attribute in camel case.

Here is the [Reference to This Answer!](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/an-angularjs-directive-with-itself-as-the-attribut)

Answer (score 0):

you must eval the value of the attribute inself. The isolate scope is not one of my favorites kind of scopes for a directive. Instead you can use, scope = true, to inherit from the parent controller. This will allow you to use all the variable exposes on the parents scopes.

in your case.

```
angular.module("main.directives").directive("todo", function() {

   return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: true,
      replace: false,
      templateUrl: "todo.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {   

           scope.todo = scope.$eval(attributes[todo]);

      }
   };
});
```

now your todo directive could be used. Like any other ng- directive.

example:

```
<div todo="getTodoList()"></div>
<div todo="[{description:'hahahha'}]"></div>
```